# ProtoBuf: How to reuse FieldDescriptor for new Messages? How to efficiently get field values from dynamic Messages?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reflection, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I’m currently working on a project in which I want to use Google Protocol Buffers (C++) to serialize and deserialize data. The application has the following requirements:

1. One requirement is to NOT use the standard approach of generating pre-compiled C++ classes from `.proto` files (using protoc). Instead I’m using the `google::protobuf::compiler::Importer` to import my `.proto` files at runtime and then dynamically create `google::protobuf::Message`’s using the `google::protobuf::DynamicMessageFactory`. With this approach I can already serialize/deserialize byte arrays/messages without generating the C++ classes beforehand.
2. Performance: I’m expecting new byte streams roughly every 50 ms so parsing a byte array and reading values from the dynamically created message must be quite efficient. For the parsing step I’m just using the standard `ParseFromArray(…)` method to get my message. For now, I don’t see the need to optimize this step. Instead I’m currently looking for a way to retrieve the values more efficiently.

I know that 1. and 2. kind of contradict each other because using the `DynamicMessageFactory` is probably more expensive than generating pre-compiled C++ classes, but unfortunately 1. is a hard requirement and cannot be changed.

To retrieve the values of my parsed message I’m currently using `google::protobuf::Reflection` and `google::protobuf::Descriptor` to iterate through my message until the corresponding `google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor` is found. Since iterating through the message is quite inefficient, especially when a message is expected to have ~1000 fields, I thought of caching the found `FieldDescriptor` in a map and then reuse the cached `FieldDescriptor`’s for other messages without iterating through each message again (since all my messages have the same structure anyway). This approach was proposed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/p1IjHHHpAl0). Unfortunately I didn’t manage to get it to work (see my simplified example code below). Can you guys help me? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

```
int main()
{
  MyUtil util; // My protobuf utility class

  int size;
  uint8_t* data = util.GenerateByteArray(&size); // Generate sample byte array

  Message* message1 = util.ParseFromArray(data, size);
  util.SetDouble(message1, "position.x", 1.111);

  Message* message2 = util.ParseFromArray(data, size);
  util.SetDouble(message2, "position.x", 2.222);

  cout << util.GetDouble(message1, "position.x") << endl;
  cout << util.GetDouble(message2, "position.x") << endl;

  // This works as expected if my GetDouble method iterates through the whole message for every new message.
  // But if I try to cache my FieldDescriptors I get the wrong output (see below).

  return 0;
}

class MyUtil
{
private:
  // The cached descriptors
  const Message* mTempMessage = nullptr;
  const FieldDescriptor* mTempField = nullptr;

public:
  MyUtil() { /*Initializing and importing .proto files*/ }

  // ... Some other methods

  double GetDouble(const Message* message, const string& path)
  {
    if (mTempField)
    {
      // Problem: This doesn't work if I only pass the actual 'message2' so I attempted to also cache mTempMessage.
      // But mTempMessage will always refer to the original message1 from which mTempField was retrieved.
      // This is why util.GetDouble(message2, "position.x") will always only return the value of message1.
      // So I know why my output is wrong but I don't know how the correct solution should look like.
      return mTempMessage->GetReflection()->GetDouble(*mTempMessage, mTempField);
    }

    vector<string> fieldNames;
    boost::split(fieldNames, path, boost::is_any_of(".")); // "position.x" => ["position", "x"]

    vector<string>::iterator iterator = fieldNames.begin();
    vector<string>::iterator last = fieldNames.end() - 1;

    return GetDouble(message, &iterator, &last);
  }

  double GetDouble(const Message* message, vector<string>::iterator* pathIterator, vector<string>::iterator* pathLast)
  {
    // Get FieldDescriptor using message->GetDescriptor()->FindFieldByName(...)
    const FieldDescriptor* field = GetField(message, **pathIterator);

    if (*pathIterator != *pathLast)
    {
      // Field "position": Is another message, so call recursively for next field
      (*pathIterator)++;

      // Get the inner "position" message using Reflection
      const Message* messageField = GetMessageField(message, field);

      return GetDouble(messageField, pathIterator, pathLast);
    }
    else if (field->type() == FieldDescriptor::TYPE_DOUBLE)
    {
      // Field "x": Actual value can be retrieved

      // Caching the found FieldDescriptor (and also the current "position" message)
      mTempMessage = message;
      mTempField = field;

      return message->GetReflection()->GetDouble(*message, field);
    }
    else
    {
      // Return some invalid value
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You need to cache the whole path-worth of field descriptors, not just the leaf. You can't retrieve "position.x" in one step - you need to retrieve a submessage named `position`, and then a field named `x` from that. So you need two field descriptors.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @IgorTandetnik! With this approach I was finally able to reuse the FieldDescriptors on new Messages with a significant performance boost.